# Sync animation for scroll in collection view within table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uicollectionview

I have collection views (in *plural*) inside a table view of many sections. Just so we're clear, a single table view with many sections with only one row each being that row an individual collection view.

[image]

All set up is working just fine, the data is well divided and delegates are all wired up recognizing everything they need to recognize. My problem is kind of simple but difficult at the same time: I want to scroll to specific collection view's position whenever I need to find a specific cell in animated fashion.

So far I'm able to jump with no problem to both table section (indexPath.section) and collection item (indexPath.row). The issue arises when I need to scroll (simultaneously) with animation.

*My findings so far*

1. I'm only able to achieve my current goal deactivating scroll animations for `UITableView` (`UICollectionView` can perform well with/out it)
2. Whenever I set `UITableView` *selectRow* or *scrollToRow* animation flags to *true* then the app crashes (99% sure this happens because I'm trying to access and "invisible" section due to the animation hasn't shown it yet).

Relevant snippets of code

---

```
@IBOutlet weak var albumTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var stickersCollectionView: UICollectionView!

func locateCell() {
    ...
    let stickerIndex = methodThatReturnsExactIndex()
    let sectionIndex = IndexPath(row: 0, section: stickerIndex.section)
    albumTableView.selectRow(at: sectionIndex, animated: false, scrollPosition: .top)
    let rowIndex = IndexPath(item: stickerIndex.row, section: 0)
    stickersCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: rowIndex, at: 0, animated: true)
}
```

---

I was thinking in experiment with the `UIScrollViewDelegate` (detecting when the *tableview* and the *collectionview* stopped in order to perform the scrolling) but that would imply spreading global variables around the code and experience tough me that's just racing conditions waiting to happen. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If m not wrong you first want to animate to that section of tableView by vertical scrolling and then horizontally scrolled to specific instant. All this animation should be occur on a single event. For Example on arriving some push notification.

Answer (score 0):

First Scroll your `tableView` to that specific index with/without animation. This will make that cell visible now get your cell by providing that `indexPath` so you could access the `collectionView` object inside your `tableViewCell`. Then ask you `collectionView` to scroll to specific `indexPath` with/without animation.
Take another global bool to store that tableView is begin scrolling. Also store both `indexPath` used for collection and tableView and use tab

```
tableViewIsScrolling = true
let yourSelectedIndexPathForTableView = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4)//store it globally
let yourSelectedIndexPathForCollectionView = IndexPath(row: 10, section: 0)//store it globally

tableView.scrollToRow(at: yourSelectedIndexPathForTableView, at: .middle, animated: false)



func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if tableViewIsScrolling {
        tableViewIsScrolling = false
        //Perform your scrolling of CollectionView
        guard let yourCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: yourSelectedIndexPathForTableView) as? YourCell else {return}
        yourCell.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: yourSelectedIndexPathForCollectionView, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole point is having them both animating the scrolling. That snippet of code you shared is pretty much what I already have in my project working (since it dismisses `UITableView` animation)

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the question. I went down that road and it's a whole lot of variables and states that I had to introduced to the code, it simple isn't testable nor maintainable on the long run. Thanks anyway